# How do I pass data to a component using Props in Vue2?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-cli

I have created a .Vue file to feature information on a cafe (Cafe Details Page). However, I would like to take parts of this details page and make it its own component, in order to manage any template updates more efficiently.

Therefore, I have created a Component (CafeHeader.vue) inside a components folder. I am trying to pass down the data from my array (Which is being used on my Cafe Details page) to this component using Props. However, I can't seem to get it to work.

The template for my **Cafe Details Page** is as below:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-for="cafe in activeCafe">
            <CafeHeader v-bind:cafes="cafes" />
            <div class="content">
                <p>{{ cafe.cafeDescription }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import CafeHeader from "./../../components/CafeHeader";
import cafes from "./../../data/cafes"; // THIS IS THE ARRAY
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            cafes: cafes
        };
    },
    components: {
        CafeHeader,
    },
    computed: {
        activeCafe: function() {
            var activeCards = [];
            var cafeTitle = 'Apollo Cafe';
            this.cafes.forEach(function(cafe) {
                if(cafe.cafeName == cafeTitle){
                    activeCards.push(cafe);
                }
            });
            return activeCards;
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

Then, in a components folder I have a component called **CafeHeader** where I am wanting to use the data from the array which is previously imported to the Cafe Details page;

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-for="cafe in cafes">
            <h1>Visit: {{cafe.cafeName}} </h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
        export default {
  name: "test",
  props: {
      cafes: {
          type: Array,
          required: true
      }
  },
  data() {
      return {
          isActive: false,
          active: false
      };
  },
  methods: {}
};
</script>
```

If in the CafeHeader component I have `cafe in cafes`, it does render data from the cafes.js However, it is every cafe in the list and I want just a single cafe.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-for="cafe in cafes">
            <h1>Visit: {{cafe.cafeName}} </h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: You have a typo in your computed property. Your variable `CafeTitle` is capitalized but you write it `cafeTitle` inside the foreach. You could also shorten your computed property to a one-liner `return this.cafes.filter(cafe => cafe.name === "Apollo Cafe")`.

Comment: I see you don't have any `<script>` tags surrounding your javascript code. Is that a copy/paste error, or is it like that in your project?

Comment: I am using script tags in my project, just didnt have them on here around the JS

Comment: I sadly can't tell what else it could be then. Copy/pasting your code into a local project works as i would expect. Without any errors.

Comment: Thank you @Hiws I very much appreciate your guidance. I am a bit closer as my component is rendering the title of all cafes in my array and not the computed property to just a specific cafe based on its name.

Answer (score 0):

The component also needed `activeCafes` on the `v-for`

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-for="cafe in activeCafes">
            <h1>Visit: {{cafe.cafeName}} </h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```